# How to save file in root folder of android when app target to (Android 11 / API 30) or later?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-developer-api, android-11, scoped-storage

If we run the android app target to version 10 or below, we can set the below flag in the AndroidManifest file to access the root folder of the device.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

But Google anymore will not going to support that from Android 11. Check the link:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage

So how can I manage the scoped storage from my application (**I am developing a Xamarin forms app that supports Android & iOS**)?

Comment: In root of external storage is not possible wilhout all files access. Just save your files in the Documents folder on root of external storage.

Comment: @blackapps But I have a requirement to save only in the root folder, not in any special folder or path.

Comment: `all files access` Or use SAF.

Answer (score 1):

The below documentation links will give you the clear idea about storage related updates and APIs provided in api 30 (Android 11)

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage?authuser=1

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Answer (score 0):

add the following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

android 11 / API 30 = "R", so check permission with following function:

```
private boolean checkRWPermissions() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
    } else {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionActivity.this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionActivity.this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

if result of checkRWPermissions() is false, ask permissions this way:

```
private void requestPermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        }
    } else {
        //below android 11
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PermissionActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

handle permission callback for android "R"=API 30:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2296) {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                // perform action when allow permission success
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

handle permission callback below android "R" = android 11:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                    // perform action when allow permission success
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

copied: Thoriya Prahalad